# Exception on this line of code

Tags: java

```
if(str.contains("final"))
{
    id = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(18, str.length() - 6));    
}
System.out.println(id);
```

This line of code `id = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(18, str.length() - 6));`
I got the output as "final year" but it throws an illegalnumberformat exception 
For input string: " final Year"

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Product.main(Product.java:47)
```

How to solve this issue?

I have a text file which has both string and int in it like

final year
 93
 93 
 90
 91.
 In this input given,I need to find the "final year" string and display the count of the number's below it without repetition.How can I do that

Comment: Well the problem is that `" final Year"` can't be parsed as an integer, but it's not at all clear why you expected this to work in the first place. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You need to provide more context.  What are the contents of `str`? How do you know that's the substring that contains the numeric bit?

Comment: `str.substring(18, str.length() - 6)`, this thing is not returning something that can be converted to `Integer`

Comment: What is the exact content of `str`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure what you pass into Integer.parseInt() is an int or a String.
If it is a String, make sure it is in numeric format (ie: "2" is okay but "two" is not)

Comment: I have a text file which has both string and int in it like      final year
 93
 93 
 90
 91.                                                               In this input given,I need to find the "final year" string and display the count of the number's below it without repetition.How can I do that

Answer (score 6):

It means what it says.  " final Year" is not a number.

Comment: okay.My code is that If my string matches the "final year" it should read the next line of the input given and return the result.How could I do that.If you dont get it,I can paste the entire code here.

Comment: Presumably if the string contains final, you want to read a new string, rather than immediately try to parse it as a number.